# Official laravel recommendation of .gitignore confuse me with unused folder

Tags: php, laravel, gitignore

Following is the link for the official Laravel recommendation of .gitignore

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.gitignore

This contains :

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
/.vscode
/.vagrant
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
```

I've the following confusion :

1. "/public/hot" when this will be used. did anybody has even seen the "hot" folder used inside the 'public' folder so far?
2. "/public/storage" when this will be used. did anybody have seen the 'storage' folder used inside 'public' so far?
3. As "/public/hot" & "/public/storage" are not an obvious part of laravel framework, why is this recommended to add in gitignore?
4. Why other public subfolders like "public/css/*, public/js/*, public/fonts/*" are not added above in the list as it would be generated based on "resource/" content.
5. "/storage/*.key" when this "key" extension file will be created?
6. Why other storage subfolder like "storage/framework/cache/*, storage/framework/sessions/*, storage/framework/views/*, storage/logs/*" are not added in above list ?
7. What is the best .gitignore list for Laravel 5.4 onwards?

I'd appreciate your thought. Thanks.

Comment: About the `hot` folder: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/17571. Take a look at the history of the `.gitignore` file and you may find out about the rest.

Comment: Storage folder is properly the folder where images and documents uploaded are stored. as for other folders like storage/logs, storage/framework, they can have their own .gitignore file inside each folder... this usually prevent errors of permissions when creating folders and just have them created by default, ignoring the files inside. But why does it bother you to have folders over there you might not necessarily use? Btw: "Best .gitignore list" is a opinion based question, those kind of questions will only get you downvotes on SO.

Comment: @Dammeul Storage is for whatever you want. It is commonly used to store uploaded files, like images.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. `public/hot` is a temporary file used by webpack dev server.
2. `public/storage` is a symlink to `storage/app/public`. See [filesystem documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk) for more info.

   - created by `php artisan storage:link`
3. `public/hot` is only used during development and is created every time `npm run hot` is ran. `public/storage` is just a symlink and needs to be created on production and development environments alike.
4. The web server serves your assets from these directories.
5. These are secret encryption keys for services like OAuth.

   - Passport's `php artisan passport:keys` is one example of where they come from. See [deploying passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#deploying-passport) for more info.
6. The framework needs these for internal usage.
7. I would say the `.gitignore` in the official repository is probably a pretty good starting point.